# How to check not equal in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In my query shows some error near != this.I want to get ids that is not in the appoinment table

```
   function getFilterStudents()
   {   
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('student_application.applicant_id,student_application.applicant_first_name,student_application.father_name,student_application.mother_name,student_application.applicant_grade');
    $this->db->from('student_application');
    $this->db->join('appointment,appointment.applicant_id !=student_application.applicant_id');
    $this->db->where('student_application.filter_status',1) ;
    $filter_students=$this->db->get();
    return $filter_students;
   }
```

Comment: I want the ids that not in the appoinment table

Comment: After `appointment` you have `,` but it should be `','` to separate the "table" parameter from the "ON" parameter.  Off-Topic Typo.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use QueryBuilder for this, Since you're not using user input, which means your query would be OK if you run it directly.

```
function getFilterStudents() {

            $q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `student_application` WHERE 
                 `applicant_id` NOT IN(SELECT `applicant_id` FROM `appointment`)
                 AND `filter_status` = 1');
            return $q->result();
}
```

We are using a subQuery to retrieve all applicants ids in appointments table, And in the main query we are telling it to return all rows that its applicant_id doesn't exists in our subQuery.

I have intentionally removed the use of distinct, since I guess you should not be having multiple applications which contains the same applicant_id, If that's not the case, then you can use distinct function again.

This returns the results set directly as opposed to what you were doing (You were returning a Query Resource which means you're calling ->result() some where in your view or controller And this is really not the job of a controller or a view).

Comment: This popped up in the review queue. Can you explain your answer a bit? Thanks.

Comment: @Will, I thought it was self-explanatory that's why I kept it small ... Anyway, I have added my explanation to this in-case the OP doesn't understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, a lot of times the code just speaks for itself. But SO will always pop code-only answers into the review queue, where, who knows what people will do to it. Looks like a high quality answer now! :)

Comment: It is very rare that someone should _need_ QueryBuilder, but the idea behind embracing it throughout your entire project is for stability/portability.  If you would happen to need to change db drivers, CI will automatically use the appropriate syntax.  For professional projects, all database interactions should fully implement query building methods unless there is a required technique that is not available via the builder methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a NOT IN subquery by eliminating the JOIN and adding a where clause like this one (keep in mind you have to tell CI to not escape the condition, hence the NULL, FALSE arguments):

```
$this->db->where('`applicant_id` NOT IN (SELECT `applicant_id` FROM `application`)', NULL, FALSE);
```

Here is the whole thing:

```
 function getFilterStudents()
   {   
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('applicant_id, applicant_first_name, father_name, mother_name, applicant_grade');
    $this->db->from('student_application');
    $this->db->where('student_application.filter_status',1);
    $this->db->where('`applicant_id` NOT IN (SELECT `applicant_id` FROM `application`)', NULL, FALSE);
    $filter_students=$this->db->get();
    return $filter_students;
   }
```